# Catching part of a JSON response and saving into a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, rest

I have a question I've spent the past few days with my friend google trying to answer. This is the code from a project I'm currently working on and I'm trying to interface with two API's.

What you see here is a call to the first API using the GOT library formatting to receive a JSON response.

```
    var products

    //Printify call for products list
    (async () => {
        try{
            const list = await redd('shops/shopId/products.json');


            //Catch the Data array and save it into the variable products
            var obj = new JSONObject(response);
            products = obj.getJSONArray("data");


        }

        catch(error) {

        }


    })();

    //Print the variable products to the console
    console.log(products)
```

I create a new JSONObject from the response and grab the Data Array from that response and put it in the Variable products which was defined outside this function. Finally I'm trying to print the variable to the console.

Eventually I will need to take that "data" Array and parse for specific items inside it (i.e. `title: , description: , images:`) and pass it as a value into the next API.

Currently I'm getting a "undefined" response from the console.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong, hoping that I can get some help or direction. Anything is appreciated, thank you all in advance!

Comment: What is JSONObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to get it all working. It's actually been a minute since I solved, but wanted to make sure it worked. Here is the final code that ended up working for me:

```
//Config for a new GOT instance, to use redd as the variable with the attached headers and options
const redd = got.extend({
    prefixUrl: 'https://api.printify.com/v1',
      responseType: 'json',
      headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + apiKey 
      }
});

var productsParsed //Setting up global variable to accept the array from the JSON response body

//Printify call for products list
getProducts = async () => {
    try{
        const response = await redd('shops/' + shopId + '/products.json');
        productsParsed = response.body.data; //Data is the array in the body I need access to, and saving that into the var productsParsed

        //Returning the var with the new value
        return productsParsed

    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log(error.response);
    }
};

getProducts().then(console.log); //Printing the return value from getProducts() which verifies the var contains the needed value
```

So the solution ended up being fairly simple. I just didn't fully understand the GOT structure. I had to use dot notation to pin down my return statement. After figuring that out I was able to use my global variable that I had set up to accept the value of the JSON response body. Thank you all for your suggestions and assistance. I hope this post is able to help any others in a similar situation to myself.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined an async function, but you haven't awaited its result.

I think adding `await` in front of the call site would fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's an async function the console.log is called before the async function is finished. Move it inside the async function and it should work.

```
var products

    //Printify call for products list
    (async () => {
        try{
            const list = await redd('shops/shopId/products.json'); // we wait for the response here


            //Catch the Data array and save it into the variable products
            var obj = new JSONObject(response);
            products = obj.getJSONArray("data");

            //Print the variable products to the console will work here
            console.log(products)
        }

        catch(error) {

        }
    })();
```

Comment: should it be var obj = new JSONObject(list) ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the GOT library so I'm not sure. @RowanC

Comment: @Will after moving it inside the async function I now get no response from the console. Even trying RowanC suggestion it doesn't give me anything.

Comment: What is `redd`? What do you get if you `console.log(list)` after it is returned?

Comment: @Will In GOT you start with a const Variable, in my instance it's named `redd` that provides a prefix url , response type, and headers. Also in order to  `console.log(list)` I have to get rid of my JSON catch and then it prints all the information about the call, but not the JSON response from the API.

Comment: @Christian could you provide a codesandbox or snippet reproduction of the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Will Thank you for your assistance, I finally got it all working as you can see in my answer. Apologize for not being able to create a reproducible example, but wasn't 100% sure how to go about that. Still, thank you again for your assistance.